# Laravel Redirect from Helper Class

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to redirect to an external URL from a helper class.

Here's my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Lead;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App;
use Helper;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function entities_get() {
        Helper::my_function(); // <---- Call my Helper class method to redirect.

        return view( 'template' );
    }
}
```

Here's my helper class used in the controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

class Helper
{
    public static function my_function()
    {
        return redirect()->away( 'https://www.google.com' ); // <---- Not redirecting.
    }
}
```

Why is the redirect() not working inside my_function()? Do I need to include some Laravel classes using the PHP "use" statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `send` method and it will work.

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

class Helper
{
    public static function my_function()
    {
        return redirect()->away('https://www.google.com')->send();
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but why do I need to put ->send()? It's not necessary if I use return redirect()->away( 'https://www.google.com') in my controller.

Comment: It will work without `send` method but you need to return a response from the controller in that case like `return Helper::my_function();`

Comment: @GTSJoe the controller sends* what you return in it. helpers are not expected to return a response. You should move the logic in the controller so you can seperate responsabilities

Comment: @MichalOravec you dont need the `return` when you use send.

Comment: @MichalOravec No he was just saying if I wanted to avoid using send(), I can use return Helper::my_function(); instead.

Comment: I know, I meant that he needs to use `return` when he doesn't use `send()`.